# What force does a floating object exert on the liquid it is floating on?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, pressure, fluid-statics, free-body-diagram, buoyancy

When something floats, it is due to the buoyant force from the liquid onto the object, but what force does the object exert in response down on the liquid? I feel as if the object would have to exert a downward force on the liquid due to Newton's Third Law, but I haven't been able to figure out what it would be.

Comment: You are correct.  It exerts a compressive stress equal to the liquid pressure.  What did you expect?

Comment: What is the name of the force that is the compressive stress? because stress is not a force, if I'm not mistaken. It am wondering how to represent the force of the object on the water in a free-body diagram.

Comment: The object is in equilibrium. So, its weight is balanced by the buoyance force of the liquid. The rest is action-reaction law.

Comment: @Claudio Saspinski That is not an action-reaction pair.

Comment: @Chet Miller what I said is that based on that equilibrium, it is possible to know the force of the object on the liquid by $3^{rd}$ law.

Comment: @Eva What I am saying is that the compressive stress at every location on the surface of the object matches the liquid pressure.

Comment: @Claudio Saspinski The reaction force to the weight of the body is the gravitational force the body exerts on the earth.

Comment: @Chet Miller yes, that is one pair. But there is another one...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116508/discussion-between-claudio-saspinski-and-chet-miller).

Comment: @ClaudioSaspinski im not sure if you're intending to chat with me, but my reputation on here is too low to participate in a chat room

Comment: @ChetMiller, if I were trying to draw a free body diagram for the water, would I have to draw any arrows for the force of the object "pressing" down on the water? This may be an obvious question, but I am not at a very high level of physics. Thank you!

Comment: @eva the liquid does the buoyant force on the floating object (that happens to be equal to the weight of the object because it is at rest). So the object does the same force on the liquid.

Comment: @ClaudioSaspinski but I thought that buoyant force only pushed upwards?

Comment: @Eva Of course you would.  Rather than a point force, it would be a distributed force resulting from the compressive stresses at the surface.

Comment: @eva buoyant force pushes upwards on the object. The object reacts with an equal force on the liquid but downwards.

Comment: On some thought, if a body is submerged in water and it exerts compressive stress, how does that force disturb the hydrostatic scenario?

Comment: @ChetMiller " I am saying is that the compressive stress at every location on the surface of the object matches the liquid pressure" I get that there is internal forces which cancel of the forces applied on the body by pressure, but by third law the structure should put an opposite reaction onto the fluid itself. The pressure is due to weight of liquid above, so I don't think that pressure and the pressure caused as reaction from the structure is equal

Comment: @Buraian The pressure distribution exerted by the liquid on the surface of the body causes a deformational response of the material comprising the body.  The material responds by developing a stress distribution both internally and at its interface with the fluid.  The manner in which the fluid pressure at the interface comes about is irrelevant.  The interface is massless, so the force per unit area exerted by the fluid on one side of the interface must be equal in magnitude and opposite in direction to the force per unit area exerted by the solid on the interface.  So the two pressures are =

Comment: I don't quite understand the concept of a massless interface, how does one understand that object/visualize it? Secondly, How does a massless interface lead to the force on both sides being equal, are you saying the force somehow passes through to affect the bulk of material without the two bodies actually making contact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the bottom of the floating mass its weight would be pushing downwards on the water, and the water pressure on the bottom would be pushing upwards on the object. This would be the up and down action reaction pair from its buoyancy. There is also a sideways action reaction of water pressure on opposite sides of the object but they cancel each other out. As you know, a buoyant object displaces its weight in water so it will make the water level rise the same as adding its weight of water would.

Comment: do you mean vertically? I dont understand how something can push "horizontally" downwards/upwards

Comment: I meant the horizontal bottom part of the object would have the up and down forces acting on it, and the vertical part of the object the side pressure, sorry for the confusion, I will edit.

Answer (score 5):

The floating object exerts exactly the same forces on the fluid as the fluid it displaced would have exerted.  This is the essence of Archimedes principle: the rest of the fluid does not notice that the displaced fluid  is gone.

Comment: So if I were trying to draw a free body diagram for the liquid, I would not have to include a force arrow of the object 'pressing' down on the water?

Comment: @Eva Sure you would.  The integral of the local solid compressive stress over the surface would be the force you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I'm at that level of physics- is there a simple way to label the arrow? The only forces I have been introduced for Air resistance, Wind, Drag, Thrust, Buoyant force, Friction, Tension, Normal force, Electrostatic force, and Magnetic force. Which category would this force be considered?

Comment: Well add Distributed Compressive Stress Force to your list, if you insist of it having a name.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is going to be a bit different from others but give it a try.

Newton's third law says that if a body $A$ exerts a force on a body $B$ then the body $B$ will alao exert the same **type** of force of same magnitude and in opposite direction. The origins of the both the forces are same.

**What do you think why are all water molecules in a container not falling down due to gravity (considering in vacuum) ?**

This is because every water molecule is pushing or repelling every other water molecule since the distance between them is less due to gravity. See the graph of variation of intermolecular forces with separation between two atoms

[image]

When you drop a body in it, the water molecules are pressed more against each other and the repelling forces increase (notice the change in repelling force with a little change in distance). Also there is a repelling force between the atoms of the body and the water molecules (for the same reasons), which contribute in its floating.

You can see that the force between two molecules are acting on both the molecules and the force is of the same type. So, the floating body also applies the same type of force on water molecules.

Apart from this , increased force between water molecules also contribute in rising of water level (if you want to know how , comment below).

Hope it helps .

Comment: @Eva was that helpful ?

Comment: yes, this was helpful! I'm still a little confused- do you mean that I can accurately say that the water exerts buoyant force on the object and the object exerts buoyant force back on the water?

Comment: @Eva yes both are exactly the same in origin and hence you can say that the object also exerts buoyant force. Btw you can appreciate the answer (if you want) by upvoting it .

Comment: @Eva also you have received three answers till now . If any one of them are satisfactory then you can accept them .